# LinkageError: loader constraint violation - BundleClassLoader - docx4j

Tags: apache-felix, docx4j

Am using **org.docx4j.Docx4J** in a desktop application **(JDK1.8)** for converting WORD file to PDF and it all works fine.

The same desktop application, when launched as an OSGi plug-in **(JDK1.8)**, throws NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException for the above mentioned conversion.

Upon adding the below dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-JAXB-Internal', version: '8.2.8'  
implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl', version: '8.2.8'
implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-JAXB-MOXy', version: '8.2.8'
```

I get the below error (in **bold**):

java.lang.linkageerror: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader.getNamespaceContext()Ljavax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext;"
**the class loader** "" (instance of org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@2dd2e270,
child of sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@277050dc) **of the current class**, org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/record/namespaces/UnmarshalNamespaceContext,
**and the class loader**  **for the method's defining class**, javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader,
**have different Class objects** for the type javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext used in the signature

```
java.lang.linkageerror: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader.getNamespaceContext()Ljavax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext;"
the class loader "<unnamed>" (instance of org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@2dd2e270,
child of sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@277050dc) of the current class, org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/record/namespaces/UnmarshalNamespaceContext,
and the class loader <bootstrap> for the method's defining class, javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader,
have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext used in the signature
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.namespaces.UnmarshalNamespaceContext.getPrefix(UnmarshalNamespaceContext.java:58)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl.resolveNamespaceUri(UnmarshalRecordImpl.java:1338)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.SAXFragmentBuilder.startElement(SAXFragmentBuilder.java:78)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLRelationshipMappingNodeValue.setupHandlerForKeepAsElementPolicy(XMLRelationshipMappingNodeValue.java:231)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLAnyObjectMappingNodeValue.startElement(XMLAnyObjectMappingNodeValue.java:179)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl.startElement(UnmarshalRecordImpl.java:864)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parseEvent(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:138)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:102)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:89)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:940)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:655)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:637)  
at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.<init>(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:132)
```

Per the suggestions, when i add just these three to my plug-in bundle:

```
implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl', version: '8.2.8'
implementation group: 'javax.xml.stream', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0-2'
```

i have:

```
ClassCastException: com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory (loaded by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@0x0000000100046e00) cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
(loaded by org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100240038)
(found matching super class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory loaded by , but needed loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100240038)
at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.<init>(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:115)
```

I really hope someone from DOCX4J and/or APACHE FELIX kindly help me out. All of this has to do with bundle class loading!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dependency for the JAXB-API, because it is no longer part of modern JREs:

`implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'`

In addition, you need to add one (and only one) of the three dependencies you added. The first one is probably not going to work, because of the removal of JAXB, so I would go for the second one:

`implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl', version: '8.2.8'`

Remove the two other dependencies you added.

Comment: thanks for formatting my question. However when i add just these two:  implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1' & implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl', version: '8.2.8' to my plug-in bundle, i get the rudimentary error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException
 at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:638)
 at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:418)
 at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:287)

Comment: You could add this dependency to find out more about the Exception: implementation group: 'javax.xml.stream', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0-2'

Comment: With that i have: ClassCastException: com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory (loaded by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@0x0000000100046e00) cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
(loaded by org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100240038)

Comment: (found matching super class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory loaded by , but needed loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100240038)
at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.<init>(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:115)

Comment: To be honest, i have tried all of these and would really hope someone from DOCX4J and/or APACHE FELIX kindly help me out. All of this has to do with bundle class loading! Thanks!

Comment: I know that all this has to do with bundle class loading. I had a similar problem a few months back with running docx4j on Apache Liberty with the MOXy implementation. I ended up forking and fixing docx4j myself. Good luck with waiting for the docx4j and/or Apache Felix folks to help you out. Thanks!

Comment: Lass uns sehen! Interesting as well as disappointing in a way that you had to "fix" yourself. Would like to hear more. Thanks!